# How to prove closure property for $x\cdot y = \frac{x + y}{1 + \frac{xy}{c^2}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given $G$ has elements in the interval $(-c, c)$. Group operation is defined as:
$$x\cdot y = \frac{x + y}{1 + \frac{xy}{c^2}}$$

How to prove closure property to prove that G is a group?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde It's indeed a group! I proved it.Very nice problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$-c\leq\frac{(x+y)c^2}{c^2+xy}<c,$$ which is
$$(c-x)(c-y)>0$$ for the right inequality and
$$(c+x)(c+y)>0$$ for the left inequality.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to write $x=c\tanh a,\,y=c\tanh b$ with $a,\,b\in\Bbb R$ (these are called [rapidities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity)), then show $x\cdot y=c\tanh (a+b)$. This proves $G$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R,\,+)$.

Comment: Surely $y = c \tanh b$?

Comment: @ConnorHarris Fixed. (Relativity is often simplified with $c=1$.)